# How can I get a specific part of element in arrays

Tags: javascript

The title may a little confusing. But i think it is clear:

```
var a = ["A1", "B13", "C123"];
```

I want to ignore first value in elements and get rest of them. So my new array should look like this:

```
var b = ["1", "13", "123"];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.map()` to create a new Array of modified values of the original.

```
var b = a.map(function(item) {
    return item.slice(1);
});
```

---

This iterates the original Array, passes each item in the Array as the first argument to the function, and sets the return value of the function as the values for the new Array.

For IE8 and lower, you'll need to implement a patch. One is available [from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Compatibility).

Comment: Is there someone still using IE8 and lower out there? thank you by the way.

Comment: You're welcome, and yes, IE8 has many users still in general, though perhaps you target users that don't use IE8. IE6/7 have relatively few users at this point.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), you can return a new array which is generated by passing every element in the existing array through a function:

```
var b = a.map(function(v) {
    return v.substr(1);
});
```

Note that `.map` is an ES5 function that doesn't exist on older browsers.  A shim is available at the above link.

Comment: substr is the least standard and worst performer out of the 3 (substring and slice being the other alternatives), Slice is really the one to use these days imho

Answer (score 2):

```
var b = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
{
    b[i] = a[i].substring(1);
}
```

[***Live Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/annC5/)

Comment: `a[i].substring(1)` would suffice.

Comment: why are you modifying `a` instead of returning a new array?

Comment: This is the most cross-browser friendly, also faster than ´forEach´ and ´map´, not as friendly on the eye and I dislike the ´++´ notation and would use ´+= 1´, just my preference. :)

Answer (score 1):

The `forEach` way

```
var a = ["A1", "B13", "C123"],
    b = [];

a.forEach(function (element) {
    b.push(element.slice(1));
});

console.log(b);
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/wkRt3/)

The `map` way

```
var b = a.map(function (element) {
    return element.slice(1);
});
```

The `for` way

```
var l = a.length;
var b = [];

for (var i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
    b.push(a[i].slice(1));
}
```

Ultimate speed is still the for loop (except for maybe grand daddy)

So as I ended up including all of the above, it didn't feel right to leave the grand daddy of them all out of the equation.

The `while` way

```
var b = [];
var i = 0;
var l = a.length;

while (i < l) {
    b.push(a[i].slice(1));
    i += 1;
}
```

I also include a RegExp and jquery version for a bit of a giggle.

([lodash](http://lodash.com/) also has it's own map function)

You can see the [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/map-vs-foreach-on-so/5)

Comment: That `forEach` loop pretty much implements `map`. Re: edit: anywhere `forEach` is supported, `map` is supported.

Comment: @Alnitak: What's less efficient than what and in what way?

Comment: A hand crafted `.forEach` / `push` loop  should be less efficient than calling a native `.map` function

Comment: @Alnitak: Benchmarks or it didn't happen ;) If this is actually a concern, you should be using the `for` loop and avoiding the function call overhead anyways.

Comment: Haha, guess not! (Also, you should probably [use the same method](http://jsperf.com/map-vs-foreach-on-so/2) for fairness' sake.)

Comment: curious - I had expected the native `.map` call to be able to do a better job of creating the array copy than one based on hand-crafted calls to `push`.  Surprised to be wrong - maybe it needs a more substantial array to make a difference?  [FWIW, on my Chrome 26 the difference is actually pretty negligible]

Comment: Total guessing: functions that don't return anything can be optimized that much further